# laravel validation error when trying to update

Tags: php, laravel, validation

When I try to update a post if I dont change value of slug , laravel return this error:

> The slug has already been taken.

Here is my validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'name' => 'required',
  'content' => 'required',
  'excerpt' => 'required',
  'type' => 'required',
  'slug' => 'required | unique:providers'
]);
```

Comment: Please mark you question as answered if any of the answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

when you're updating records and there is unique validation is added. You should pass the **id** of which record you're inserting.

**While Update**

```
'slug' => 'required | unique:providers,slug,'.$providerId
```

**While insert**

```
'slug' => 'required | unique:providers'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `except` rule to your `unique` case to exclude the current ID from check:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
        'excerpt' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:providers,id,' . $provider->id
    ]);
```

Make the column and the `id` that you pass to use your table's data. I am just giving you an idea on what you need to add.

Comment: The second parameter in `unique` is the name of the unique field. The 5th one is the field used as primary key

Comment: I might not understand the documentation then? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique
It says if you specify the column, which I did then it will use except the ID column, otherwise it uses the name of the column which is `slug` and you will need to provide the `slug`.

Comment: yeah the documentation says `unique:table,column,except,idColumn` so `unique:providers,slug,$id,id` not `unique:providers,id,$id`. I get what you're saying, but you specified in your example the `column` (second param)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the validator to do an exception for the current entity you're updating.

```php
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
        'excerpt' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:providers,slug,'.$providerId
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

.
.

$slug = Str::slug($request->name, '-');

$exists = Provider::where('slug', $slug)->first();

if($exists) {

   $slug = $slug.'-'.rand(1000,9999);

}
```

When updating:

```
$request->validate([
   'slug' => 'required|unique:providers,slug,'.$provider_id.',id',
]);
```